# How to pass credentials to a WCF service from non .NET clients?

Tags: .net, wcf, html

I need to pass credentials(for authentication) from a non .NET client applications like HTML5,etc., to a WCF service. There is no document on net explaining this context. I spend a week of time to solve it and not yet. So please help me to figure out the situation.

Comment: @AmarPalsapure Can you explain more specifically on WebMethod? Since it will expose XMl methodology and i need credentials support to access on it